# How to compute a geodesic (homework question)

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

I am interested to compute the a geodesic in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^1$. I am not familiar with differential geometry but I know that a geodesic is the solution of the following optimization problem
$$
 \min_{\gamma\in\Gamma(a,b)}\int_0^1\dot{\gamma}(r)^2\,dr,
$$
where $\Gamma(a,b)$ is the set of piece wise continuous curves connecting $a\in\mathbb{R}$ to $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean by that "the solution to this problem is 1"? You should find a geodesic, not a number?

Comment: I mean it's 1, because of the parametrization by the arc length : $|\dot{\gamma} |\equiv1$. Note that I am not familiar with differential geometry. Thus, I might be confusing things.

Comment: Note that you cannot find an arc length parametrization of $\gamma$ if $\gamma$ is not a regular curve (it seems that you did not assume that $\gamma$ is regjular). Also, if $\gamma$ is parametrized by arc length, then the domain would not be $[0,1]$. It should be something else.

Comment: It might be easier to start by reading up on calculus of variations

Comment: Nice Idea, Dan. Any suggestions for books?

Comment: "Math Methods for the Physical Sciences", Chapter 9: Calculus of Variation, of M.L. Boas, 3rd ed. 2006, to start.